# Control-r reverse-i-search in Bash: how do you "reset" the search in Cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin, readline

How do you tell <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> reverse-i-search to "reset itself" and start searching from the bottom of your history every time?

**Background:** When using reverse-i-search in Bash, I always get stuck once it is finished searching up through the history and it cannot find any more matches. Sometimes I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and re-invoke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> a second time, expecting it to start a fresh new search from the bottom of my history. However, the "pointer" still seems to be at the previous place it left off in my history.

The problem is, I usually do not want this behavior. If I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then re-invoke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, I would like that to indicate it should restart from the bottom again and work its way back up.

I am using Cygwin on Windows, as none of the so-far mentioned solutions work.

---

<sub>This question was marked as a [potential duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765). This question is not a duplicate for the following reasons:</sub>

- <sub>The alternate question does not deal with Cygwin.</sub>
- <sub>The alternate question does not deal with how to **reset** the search to its initial state (instead it deals with simply going backward in search as well as forward).</sub>

Comment: Regarding Cygwin:  I updated my answer.  I do not use Cygwin so cannot try, but ^G may work for you in that case.

Comment: Yes it seems like that works. ^G immediately after ^R

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to forward search Bash history similarly as with CTRL-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I never tried making this the default when hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but Bash uses `readline` for input, which accepts Emacs-style keybindings by default, so you can go to the bottom using `M->` (usually either by combining Meta/<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> or by following the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key with <kbd>></kbd>).

If `M->` does not work because your terminal does not let you enter that, try `^G` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and `G` simultaneously). That is the "cancel" stroke in Emacs and usually works with `readline` too.

Answer (score 36):

My Bash works as you are expecting. Maybe hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd> can help.

Also, you can search forward using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> works if it does not send a "stop" to your terminal, i.e., if "stty -a" gives you "-ixon". You can change it by "stty -ixon".

Thanks to @Phil for reminder.

Comment: ctrl-s usually sends a stop to your terminal so unless you have that reconfigured, (stty -a will give you that), your terminal will intercept that keystroke)

Answer (score 18):

I got a confirmed answer to this question.

To reset <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, the usual Emacs key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> can do. If you want to reverse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> by one step, instead of working your way up from the bottom again, you can use  **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>** .

The trick is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is also used to pause the terminal. So you would need assign that to another key. For example, the following will set pause to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (and keep "resume" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>).

```
$ stty STOP ^w
```

Alternatively, you can also totally disable XON/XOFF (resume/pause) flow control characters by

```
$ stty -ixon -ixoff
```

This will also free up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. To re-enable pause/resume, you can do

```
$ stty ixon ixoff
```

Answer (score 5):

```
M-> ... moves to end of history
M-< ... moves to start of history
```

Your left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is most likely your Meta key.

Use `man readline` for more readline directives.