# Unable to forward search Bash history similarly as with CTRL-r

Tags: bash, search

I am trying to search my bash history similarly as with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>, but to forward direction.

It has been a pain for me, when I just hit once too often <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>, to find the previous command again.

How can you forward search your Bash history similarly as in reverse searching?

Comment: Anyone have a solution for Git Bash in Windows?

Comment: @GarretWilson: The accepted answer works for me in Git Bash (setting `stty -ixon`).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, @marco . I just now tried it again, and it does seem to work. Maybe the first time I tried it I had put something in the wrong state by using `Ctrl+S` before trying the command, or by some other key combination, or who knows what.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

You can search forward as well. From the bash info manual, "[8.2.5 Searching for Commands in the History](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html)":

> To search backward in the history for a particular string, type `C-r`.
>   Typing `C-s` searches forward through the history.

The problem with Ctrl-S however is that sometimes collides with XON/XOFF flow control (in Konsole for instance). The searching is a readline feature however, and you should be able to bind it to some other key. Update: Simpler and better is just to disable XON/XOFF by running

```
stty -ixon
```

Comment: It seems to collide with XON/XOFF all the time for me, since I cannot get Ctrl-S working. How can you bind the search to other key?

Comment: This is brilliant, but I add stty -ixon to my .profile and it doesn't seem to work for new tabs. Any ideas on how to make this work? I'd love XON/XOFF to be disabled by default.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same issue I did - if you add this to .profile it doesn't take effect. It's only when you add it to the .bash_profile that the magic happens! Thanks for a great tip - this had been driving me mad for years.

Comment: @JohnGallagher Important to note is that `.bash_profile` and `.profile` are only sourced for log-in shells. I would put this in `.bashrc` (which I source from `.profile`).

Comment: `[[ $- == *i* ]] && stty -ixon` can be used to avoid the problem [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623021/)

Comment: In case you're using PuTTY and can't/don't want to maintain `.bash_profile` on every machine you connect to, [this answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/376881/164453) works a treat.

Comment: Just to be sure. Does anyone have a scenario where you would need flow control?

Comment: @BakaKuna If you communicate with some several decades old museum computer hardware like a terminal screen or printer, then using xon/xoff might be useful. For everything else, you want it disabled.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me on lxterminal even after running `stty -ixon`?

Comment: I had to type two times `C-s` to move forward could it be done with single `C-s`?

Comment: Running `stty ixon` is not fixing the problem for me in `zsh`; anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Answering my own comment: for `zsh`, per `man zshle`, adding the two lines 
`bindkey '^r' history-incremental-search-backward` and 
`bindkey '^s' history-incremental-search-forward`
to `~/.zshrc` worked (and of course running `source ~/.zshrc` after editing to source changes).  It does take 2 invocations of Ctrl+S to start going forward again after going backwards with Ctrl+R.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it said I had already upvoted ‍♂️ I'll write it on by laptop with permanent marker this time ...

Answer (score 46):

The best trick IMHO is enabling with `pgup` and `pgdown`. just put that in your `~/.inputrc`

```
"\e[5~": history-search-forward
"\e[6~": history-search-backward
```

logout/login, type the first letters and then `pgup` or `pgdown` to search throughout history

`ctrl-R` search all lines containing words, whereas history-search-forward search lines beginning with words

Comment: You can also uncomment these 2 lines in `/etc/inputrc` (e.g. in Ubuntu).

Comment: I prefer to bind this to up and down arrow:

"\e[A": history-search-backward    and   
"\e[B": history-search-forward

Comment: What if this has no effect in bash?

Comment: @Sören This works in bash (tested version 4.4.20). Please ensure you put this in either `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc`. This will not work if placed in any of the `bashrc` files because it's not a command, it's a configuration option.

Answer (score 29):

You may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which allows for "suggest box style" filtering of Bash history with (optional) metrics based ordering i.e. it is much more efficient and faster in both forward and backward directions:

[image]

It can be easily [bound](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) to <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>

Comment: I'm in love. Quick instructions to install on Ubuntu: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install hh; hh --show-configuration >> ~/.bashrc;`

Answer (score 17):

I usually press <kbd>ESC</kbd> in terminal, and then the <kbd>></kbd>. It resets at least and then you could try press less too often <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: s/click/press/  Also, you need to press escape twice (first time to escape from the backwards search).

Comment: This is such underrated advice if one has set HISTSIZE and the like to -1.....

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to use:

`history | grep <searched expression>`

Answer (score 5):

As many have experienced, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> freezes (and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> unfreezes) the terminal because of [software flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) (XON/XOFF flow control) and you can disable it as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Although I can't say I've really intentionally used the feature, I do want the option to be able to pause a fast moving stream of terminal text, so I didn't want to completely disable it.

So instead of turning it off, I rebound the xoff function by placing the following in my .bashrc

```
stty stop '^P'
```

Which binds xoff to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (and ctrl+q still unfreezes).  I used "p" for "pause" and this does obscure the bash previous command function `previous-history`. Personally I always use the up arrow key for that so it doesn't matter to me, but you could choose a different key.

This automatically frees up <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for `forward-search-history`

Answer (score 0):

For KDE's terminal app (Konsole), you can disable flow control with XON/XOFF from settings according to [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322975/883908) answer:

> "in Konsole you can disable this feature, by going to Settings ->
> Configure Profile -> Choose current profile -> Edit Profile ->
> Advanced Tab and disable 'Enable flow control using Ctrl+S and
> Ctrl+Q'"