# In reverse-i-search (Ctrl+R ) ,Any method to switch between similar commands in history

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I think an example will be good to understand my question.

```
...
scp file1 user10@192.168.10.1:/home/user1/linuxfiles/samplecode/important
...
...
scp file1 user10@192.168.10.1:/home/user1/linuxfiles/samplecode/important/tested
...
...
```

Assume that is the order of commands in history. If I am doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `scp` it will show the last executed `scp` command ( ie the line ending with 'tested') .

But I want to locate the scp command ending with 'important'. So is there any way in this `reverse-i-search` to view all commands starting with scp, to choose the appropriate one?

Comment: Have you tried pressing CTRL-R again ?

Comment: when searching use unique words , it makes it very precise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to forward search Bash history similarly as with CTRL-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and it will traverse your history.

Comment: Thanks, is there a possibility to use Ctrl-R backwards? So if I "ctrl-R" for some time, I see the results, but I would like to go it backwards. "Shift-Ctrl-R" does not work. EDIT: The solution is on SO, see "related".

Comment: Forward search: Ctrl-S. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760474/reverse-intelligent-search-reverse-i-search-how-to-get-previous-result?rq=1

Answer (score 17):

If your search terms are a bit more complicated/ not contiguous, another option is to grep  among the `history` results, e.g.:

```
history 300 | grep scp | grep important$
```

This will return a list of commands in your history that match, such as:

```
3323  scp file1 user10@192.168.10.1:/home/user1/linuxfiles/samplecode/important
3325  scp file1 user10@192.168.10.1:/home/user1/winfiles/samplecode/important
```

And you can then execute the relevant command with `!3325`.

I sometimes find this useful when running a lot of similar commands and may have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> many times to get back to the exact command.

Answer (score 4):

There is great alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

install https://github.com/dvorka/hstr

run it with `hh`

it shows a list of you all the last commands executed (contents of ./bash_history)

if you start typing the list will be filtered based on what you type

you can use <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrows to select the desired command and select it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I found this great tool **mcfly** as a replacement to the traditional Ctrl+R and it works really well. Basically you can see ALL the results as you type and you can select the command you are looking for. You can also customize the layout etc. I really recommend it.

https://github.com/cantino/mcfly

[image: Example of mcfly session]

Comment: You are using it in mac ?

Comment: No, I'm using it on Linux but as far as I know it's supported on Mac as well.