# Getting stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device when using scp through an ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

Per the title, I'm getting the following warning when I try to `scp` through an `ssh` tunnel. In my case, I cannot `scp` directly to foo because port 1234 on device foo is being forwarded to another machine bar on a private network (and bar is the machine that is giving me a tunnel to 192.168.1.23).

```
$ # -f and -N don't matter and are only to run this example in one terminal
$ ssh -f -N -p 1234 userA@foo -L3333:192.168.1.23:22
$ scp -P 3333 foo.py ubuntu@localhost:
ubuntu@localhost's password:
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
foo.py                                          100% 1829     1.8KB/s   00:00
```

Does anyone know why I might be getting this warning about `Inappropriate ioctl for device`?

Answer (score 97):

I got the exact same problem when I included the following line on my `~/.bashrc`:

```
stty -ixon
```

The purpose of this line was to allow the use of [Ctrl-s in reverse search of bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/).

This gmane link has a solution: [(original link dead)](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.netbsd.general/7848) => [Web Archive version of gmane link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160222215720/http://comments.gmane.org:80/gmane.os.netbsd.general/7848)

> 'stty' applies to ttys, which you have for interactive login sessions.
> .kshrc is executed for all sessions, including ones where stdin isn't
> a  tty.  The solution, other than moving it to your .profile, is to
> make  execution conditional on it being an interactive shell.

[There are several ways to check for interecative shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch). The following solves the problem for bash:

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] && stty -ixon
```

Comment: Explanation of "[[ $- = *i* ]]" found here (I certainly needed it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155381/what-does-i-mean-in-bash/31155446

Comment: Glad you pasted the text from the link, as it looks like that link is dead now, and some quick searching doesn't turn up a new URL for it.

Comment: @Randall the link is dead indeed. But I hope it is temporary, as mentioned at [their homepage](http://gmane.org/).

Comment: Nope. It's gone.

Comment: exactly the same problem.  Interestingly I was getting this as an error popup on initial login on ubuntu when the offending call was in my `.profile`.  I'm a little surprised its getting sourced but hopefully this should fix

Comment: Another common practice is just to put `[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return` at the top of `.bashrc`

Comment: Should I put this line into `.zshrc` as well?

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue while executing the script remotely. After many tries didn't get any luck to solve this error. Then got an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926319/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-via-ssh-such-that-the-environment-of-the-remote-com) to run a shell script through ssh. This was an issue related to ssh, not any other command. `ssh -t "command"` -t will allocate a pseudo TTY to the ssh and this error won't come.

Comment: This actually helped

Answer (score -3):

at the end i created a blank .cshrc file ( for ubuntu 18.04). worked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.