# What does [[ $- = *i* ]] mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm installing [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt) and in the documentation they ask you to add `[[ $- = *i* ]] && source ~/liquidprompt/liquidprompt` in your `.bashrc` .

I am trying to understand the first part of the line but it's hard for a noob in bash like me. If anyone has a nice doc or the answer...

Comment: Further interesting reading: [Is this Shell Interactive?](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html) and [How can I check in bash if a shell is running in interactive mode?](http://serverfault.com/a/146747/200076)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`$-` contains the current shell options.

In `[[ ... ]]`, the right hand side of a `=` is interpreted as a pattern if not quoted. Therefore, `*i*` means `i` possibly preceded or followed by anything.

In other words, it checks wheter the `i` option is present, i.e. whether the current shell is interactive.

Comment: Approved by the liquidprompt maintainer himself (who wrote that instruction in the manual).

Answer (score 16):

It is checking whether the options for the shell `$-` contains an `i` in them. The `i` is for interactive

From the [Bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash):

> An interactive shell is one started without  non-option   arguments  and
>          without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected
>          to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with  the  -i
>          option.   PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing
>          a shell script or a startup file to test this state.

[Also relevant](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior)

Comment: Approved by the liquidprompt maintainer himself (who wrote that instruction in the manual).