# Testing whether stdin is a file vs. a pipe vs. a tty

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I know for bash and zsh, one can use e.g. `[ -t 1 ]` to determine if STDIN is an interactive tty session.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to test whether stdin is being redirected from a file, versus being piped in from a command:

```
foo < ./file
bar | foo
```

Is there any way to detect the difference between these two?  Separately, is there any way to get the path of the file being redirected from (outside of /proc/self, which is unavailable on macOS)?

Comment: What kind of answer would you expect if ./file is a named pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if `/dev/stdin` is a regular file or a pipe:

```
$ cat tmp.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /dev/stdin ]; then
    echo "file"
elif [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    echo "pipe"
fi
$ bash tmp.sh < foo.txt
file
$ echo foo | bash tmp.sh
pipe
```

This relies on `/dev/stdin` being in your file system, though.

You can also use the `stat` command, which will return information about standard input given no file name argument. As you mentioned you are using macOS, you can use the `%HT` format:

```
$ stat -f %HT
Character Device
$ stat -f %HT < foo.txt
Regular File
$ echo foo | stat -f %HT
Fifo File
```

Comment: "Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections", including /dev/stdin

Comment: `-f /dev/stdin` isn't a redirection, though.

Answer (score 0):

On many systems, `/dev/stdin` is a symbolic link. For example on openSUSE Tumbleweed, `/dev/stdin` links to `/proc/self/fd/0` (which is another symlink to `/dev/pts/0`).

The accepted answer doesn't handle that because it wasn't necessary for macOS. But readers using Linux may be interested in how to do it properly.

So, I'd do the check for a pipe first. If that fails, then do { 1) stat 2) check if is symlink 3) follow the symlink } until stat no longer tells symlink. If stat says "character special file", your shell is interactive. If not, it should be a "regular file". Too complicated, you think? Right, read on.

Note that exact wording and uppercase/lowercase may be different from system to system. For Tumbleweed, it's all lowercase.

If you're using Bash then there's another way to check if the current shell is interactive:

```
is_interactive () { [[ $- == *i* ]]; }

If is_interactive; then ...
```

See "[What does [[ $- = *i* ]] mean in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155381/what-does-i-mean-in-bash)"

The error - and I think it is an error - in the original question is to assume that the interactivity of the shell is depending solely on stdin. However, if stderr is redirected (for example to /dev/null or a log file), then there's no point in using `read -p <prompt>` to get user input because the user won't see the prompt. One would be better off using `echo` then.

For Bash, the accepted answer can be shortened to:

```
stdin_is_redirected () { [[ $- == *s* ]]; }
```

But, as said, this is not the same as interactive.

Comment: function to test if stdin is a TTY:  `isatty_stdin () { [ -t 0 ]; }`