# getting multiple issues while creating a script to update hostnames in /etc/hosts file?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sh

We've around 3000 VMs & 450 Physical servers which are Linux based servers (few of then ubuntu starting from 9.x & few of them are Susu starting 8.X & majority of them are RHEL starting from 4.x till 7.4) on all of them I need to add few hostname entries with IP details into their respective /etc/hosts files.

I've different users on each server with full sudoers access which I can use
Hence I've created a CSV file with hostname, username & password format. which contains required details to log in. Filename is "hostname_logins.csv"

I need to upload a file (i.e. hostname_list to each of these servers and then update those same details in each of the servers host files.

I'll be running this script using one RHEL 6 server. (All of the other hosts are resolvable from this server & are reachable, I've confirmed it already.)

The script is working but it's asking for accepting the host key once and also asked for the password 2 times however the 3rd time it does not asked for a password it worked automatically I guess, but need to ensure it does not askes to accept the host key or passwords.:

```
#!/bin/bash
runing_ssh()
{
while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do ssh -vveS -ttq rishee:rishee@192.168.1.105 "sudo -S -ttq < ./.pwtmp cp -p /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).bkp && sudo -S bash -c 'cat ./hostname_list >> /etc/hosts' && rm -f ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list"
done < hostname_logins.csv
}

while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do  echo $user_password > ./.pwtmp
    cat ./.pwtmp
    scp -p ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list $user_name@$hostname_login:
    runing_ssh
done < hostname_logins.csv
```

I need to make this as a single script which will work on all these servers. thanks in advance.

Comment: before the while loop do IFS=, so you split up the data properly during the read command

Comment: I really recommend ansible....

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the original copy from /tmp with sudo, but nothing else.

```
while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do  echo $myPW >.pwtmp
    scp -p ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list $user_name:$user_password@$hostname_login:
    ssh -etS $user_name:$user_password@$hostname_login "sudo -S <.pwtmp cp -p /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bkp && sudo -S <.pwtmp cat ./hostname_list >> /etc/hosts && rm -f ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list"
done < hostname_logins.csv
```

I dropped the explicit send to /tmp and the cp back to your home dir, and defaulted the location (to `$user_name`'s home dir) by not passing anything to scp after the colon. Fix that if it doesn't work for you.

I created a password file for improved security and code reuse, and sent it along with the hosts list. I added a sudo -S to each relevant command, reading from the password file.

That `[bash -c ...]` syntax doesn't work on my implementation, so I took it out.

Hope that helps.

> Update

Added -t to ssh call. Try that.

Comment: I tried your script but this is what the error I got

Comment: [root@node2 ~]# ./script1.sh
ssh: connect to host rishee port 22: No route to host
lost connection
rishee:rishee@192.168.1.105's password:
bash: .pwtmp: No such file or directory
[root@node2 ~]#

Comment: while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do  echo $myPW > .pwtmp
    scp -p ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list $user_name@$hostname_login:
    ssh -eS $user_name:$user_password@$hostname_login "sudo -S <.pwtmp cp -p /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bkp && sudo -S <.pwtmp cat ./hostname_list >> /etc/hosts && rm -f ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list"
done < hostname_logins.csv

Comment: [root@node2 ~]# ./script1.sh
rishee@192.168.1.105's password:
.pwtmp                                                                                                                                                      100%    1     0.0KB/s   00:00
hostname_list                                                                                                                                               100%  122     0.1KB/s   00:00
rishee:rishee@192.168.1.105's password:
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
[root@node2 ~]#

Comment: Added -t to ssh call. Try that.

Comment: I've worked on it a littke and finally got it working but still I've to accept the keys and enter password 2 times, but it works .... is there a way we can automate it using the same script... for your reference below is the working script

Comment: #!/bin/bash
runing_ssh()
{
while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do ssh -vveS -ttq rishee:rishee@192.168.1.105 "sudo -S -ttq < ./.pwtmp cp -p /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).bkp && sudo -S bash -c 'cat ./hostname_list >> /etc/hosts' && rm -f ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list"
done < hostname_logins.csv
}

while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do  echo $user_password > ./.pwtmp
    cat ./.pwtmp
    scp -p ./.pwtmp ./hostname_list $user_name@$hostname_login:
    runing_ssh
done < hostname_logins.csv

Comment: below is how it gets executed and asked me to accept the host key once and asked for passwords 2 times but 3rd/last time it did not ask the password.

Comment: [root@node2 ~]# ./script1.sh
rishee
The authenticity of host 'hrish-rhel6.2-repo-server (192.168.1.105)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 81:17:8e:70:e2:28:3a:c7:10:cb:44:43:d9:d1:b2:ec.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'hrish-rhel6.2-repo-server,192.168.1.105' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
rishee@hrish-rhel6.2-repo-server's password:
.pwtmp                                                                                                                                                     100%    7     0.0KB/s   00:00

Comment: hostname_list                                                                                                                                              100%  122     0.1KB/s   00:00
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
rishee:rishee@192.168.1.105's password:
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[sudo] password for rishee: [root@node2 ~]#

Comment: above output is split in 2 as it could not fit in single comment

Comment: It should only ask for the host once on a server. Try it again, make sure it skips that now.

Comment: Yes second time we run the script it skips that... but we have 3000 server so in actual prod environment it will be realy annoying to accept that key even once for all 3000 servers... :(

Comment: c.f. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047175/inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-when-trying-to-ssh) post for related errors

Comment: c.f. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/19563/how-do-i-skip-the-known-host-question-the-first-time-i-connect-to-a-machine-vi) for ways to skip the known_hosts question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157577/discussion-between-hrish-and-paul-hodges).

Comment: pluse uno for tech support (and helpful answer). Good luck to all.