# Searching your command history on macOS terminal

Tags: bash, macos, history

What is the shortcut to search my command history in macOS terminal?

For how long is the history available for searching? Where is it stored?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

How about using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>R</kbd> for searching on the `Terminal` Utility in `Mac` for searching on the command history,

```
dudeOnMac: freddy$ whoami
freddy
(reverse-i-search)`who': whoami
```

Well for controlling how long the `history` would be retained that depends on a few `shell` environment variables, `HISTFILESIZE` which is nothing but number of lines of history you want to retain. Set a huge value for it in `.bash_profile` for it to take effect

```
HISTFILESIZE=10000000
```

Comment: Also worth noting, `ctrl`+`R` shows the last, but hitting `ctrl`+`R` multiple times will give you the matches before it.

Comment: I was looking for this exact thing! -- how to see multiple matches

Comment: The default history search provided by bash doesn't provide multiple matches. You need a higher level plugin like fzf (fuzzy finder)

Answer (score 78):

Use `Ctrl` + `R` for searching a command from history in Terminal.

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

Type any substring of the command you want to search e.g. grep

```
(reverse-i-search)`grep': grep "XYZ" abc.txt
```

It will return the latest command that matches your input. If that is not the command you were searching for, keep pressing `Ctrl` + `R` for next match until you find your command.

Once you found your command press `Return` to execute it.

If you want to exit without running any command, press `Ctrl` + `G`

PS: This answer is same as suggested by Inian, just giving more details for easy usage.

Comment: while we keep pressing ctrl + R, what is the reverse of ctrl + R ? like If I am keep pressing ctrl + R  and going one by one reverse in history and now If I want to come forward one by one command in mac terminal what is the command? in linux machine I used to use CTRL + SHIFT + R to do the same but for mac its not working. any other shortcut we need to use for this use case?

Comment: @NikhilP in Mac the reverse of `ctrl` + `R` would be `ctrl` + `S`

Answer (score 28):

The command history is stored under your home folder in a hidden file called **.bash_history**. To view it's content in nano, use the following command in Terminal:

```
nano ~/.bash_history
```

Or open with your text editor (default is TextEdit):

```
open ~/.bash_history
```

In my case it's a very long list and as I scroll through seems like the last ~500 command is stored here.

Comment: @balazs630 nano is an editor, and should not be used to read files with no intention of editing. At the very least, doing so creates risk of accidental editing. Instead use less, which is a command line interactive application that provides read access with no editing capability.

Comment: History is stored in ~/.zsh_history or ~/.bash_history or ~/.history depending on your shell.

Comment: it would be `~/.zsh_history` if you use zsh. I was in awe that it stores every single command I typed since I installed zsh

Answer (score 20):

Migrating an answer to SO from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20830) on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange:

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will open the history-search-backward. Now start typing your command, this will give the first match. By pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again (and again) you can cycle through the history.

If you like to be super lazy you can bind the up/down arrow keys to perform this search, I have the following in my `.inputrc` to bind the up/down arrow key to `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward`:

```
# Key bindings, up/down arrow searches through history
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\eOA": history-search-backward
"\eOB": history-search-forward
```

Just type something (optional), then press up/down arrow key to search through history for commands that begin with what you typed.

To do this in `.bashrc` rather than `.inputrc`, you can use the syntax:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
bind '"\eOA": history-search-backward'
bind '"\eOB": history-search-forward'
```

---

### Update for ZSH on Mac

For newer MacOS laptops that no longer support bash, you can add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file to accomplish the same result:

```
bindkey "\e[A" history-search-backward
bindkey "\e[B" history-search-forward
bindkey "\eOA" history-search-backward
bindkey "\eOB" history-search-forward
```

then update your terminal session with the command `source ~/.zshrc` to have your changes take effect immediately

Comment: I tried adding bashrc, but it shows
.bashrc:1: command not found: bind

Comment: This may also require to change iTerm2 key bindings for up and down keys accordingly: <Option>+<Up> => "Send Escape Sequence" => "[A" (without quotes).

Comment: Actually, this command allows cycling through whole history, not just the commands that begin with what I typed

Comment: what is the reverse of ctrl + R ? like If I am doing pressing ctrl + R  and going one by one reverse in history and now If I want to come forward one by one command in mac terminal what is the command? in linux machine I used to use CTRL + SHIFT + R to do the same but for mac its not working. any other shortcut we need to use for this use case?

Comment: @NikhilP The reverse of `Ctrl + r` (i.e. searching **forward**) is `Ctrl + s`. Checked on macOS Ventura 13.1 (with Zsh) - it works. See the following answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/791800/814702.

Answer (score 18):

Use this command -

```
  history
```

This works on both OSX and Linux.

History is stored in ~/.zsh_history or ~/.bash_history or ~/.history depending on your shell.

History is stored for 1000 or 2000 lines depending on your system.

```
 echo $HISTSIZE
```

Comment: @HamzaZymawy do you mean size of $HISTSIZE?

Comment: Yes $HISTSIZE I want increase it

Comment: Add export HISTSIZE=<size> to your shell config file. ~/.zshrc for example in case of z shell.

Comment: This was the best solution for me, combined with `grep`, for example to find commands that include the string "ssh", use `> history | grep ssh`

Comment: `history | grep ssh` didn't work well for me on Mac because the command only returns 16 lines. Try `history 1000 | grep ssh`.

Answer (score 11):

You can also try the following:

```
history | grep 'git'
```

Where 'git' is the command you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to search specific command from history, you can do so with `reverse-i-search`. Reverse search allow you to type in any key words(any) that is part of the command you are looking for and `reverse search` navigate back to history, match previous commands incrementally and return the entire command.

It is especially useful as when one cannot remember all handy lengthy commands they use often. To do reverse-search `ctrl` + `R` and type any clue you have and that will return your previous commands matching the words you type. Then once found the command, hit `Enter` to execute it directly from search.

Answer (score 3):

> Automation AppleScript

Since you mentioned viewing your history as a quick solution, via the **Terminal.app**. You might want to automate, or quickly view history, maybe from the dock. You may use the AppleScript application as one alternative. This is an optional approach to create a simple shortcut, as to many others.

1. Open the AppleScript editor application.
2. Add your specified commands, for history.
3. Code

```
tell application "Terminal"
        do script "history"
end tell
```

4. Save as application, drag to dock for convenience.

> History Storage & Time Stored Details

`HISTSIZE` Determines how many lines will be written to the history file.

`HISTFILESIZE` Determines how long the file.

Find out how long **history is stored**:

`echo $HISTSIZE $HISTFILESIZE`

**Note:** You may also increase your command history storage size in the length of two variables. You may achieve this through `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` environment variables which are located in your `~/.bash_profile` file.

It is possible to achieve this by modifying `~/.bash_profile`, the number placeholder with **SIZE** represent's the number, lines value as example:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=SIZE # Example 1000
export HISTSIZE=SIZE # Example 10000
```

> Pre macOS 11 Big Sur

```
cat ~/.bash_history
```

`HISTFILESIZE` will only set a maximum history value which is stored to the history file when a session is started. `HISTSIZE` will determine specifically how many lines will be stored or in other words, written at the **end** of the session. If the set `HISTFILESIZE` is determined to be a large value than what `HISTSIZE` is set, you will not view history larger than your set `HISTSIZE`. The reason is that the **history** file is overwritten with the `HISTSIZE` unless using `histappend` option turned **ON**.

You may use also `histappend` to append history, If the `histappend` shell option is turned on lines are appended to the history file. Otherwise, the overwritten alternative proceeds.

[Bash GNU - histappend](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html)

> macOS 11 Big Sur

`nano ~/.zprofile`

Modify history environment variables, set to a value:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=1000
export HISTSIZE=SIZE=1000
```

Run the `source` command can be used to load any functions file into the current shell script or a command prompt.

```
source ~/.zprofile
echo $HISTSIZE $HISTFILESIZE
```

Outputs:

```
1000 1000
```

Output where some history is stored:

```
cat ~/.zsh_history
```

Answer (score 3):

`history ~` works for me on Ventura 13.4.1

Answer (score 1):

To search through history with ease, I advise you to install [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

> It's an interactive Unix filter for command-line that can be used with any list; files, command history, processes, hostnames, bookmarks, git commits, etc.

Just install it, click `ctrl` + `R`, and you'll be to scroll through you shell history, without the need to `grep` or waiting ages until the command you're waiting for pops up.

It supports Mac OS, Linux and even Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Big Sur the file is now .zsh_history

If you do vi ~/.zsh_history in the terminal you can use regex by pressing the / and then the search term.

Answer (score 0):

To review or recall recently used commands, you can just press the up arrow key to sequentially read back through the history stored in .bash_history.

Answer (score 0):

```
# USAGE: find.history cd
# filter commands in shell history by a search term and execute the selected command
function find.history {
  eval $(history | grep "$1" | tail | awk '{$1=""}1' | tail -r | peco)
}
```

You will need to have `peco` installed.

https://github.com/peco/peco

`[$]> brew install peco`