# Jump to a word in a command in Bash

Tags: bash

Consider:

```
ssh -i "key.pem" root@server.com
```

Is there a quick way to jump to the beginning of "root" in such a Bash command in the terminal, without iterating over every word/character?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Bring up the last command using up arrow. These shortcuts will help:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> - go to the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - go to the start of the line
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> - go back one word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> - go right one word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> - delete the last word

To search the command line and the command line history, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then type the search string, e.g. "roo" to search backwards for "root@...". In the example you have given, however, it will be easier just to jump forward or back by words.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> search forwards (rarely useful). (If forward searching doesn't appear to work, try [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/791800/3787051).)

See also [this page](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html) and google "Bash command line editing" for more tricks.

Comment: I am referring more to the case where there are many words in the command, and I want something like the vim /<searchword> notation where we can jump to the first instance of a search word

Comment: CTRL-R works! But, CTRL-S does not bring up any search prompt like CTRL-R, even when starting at the beginning of the line?

Comment: That's very interesting. I just copied it there for the sake of completeness from the docs, now I test it it doesn't work for me either. I can't immediately find a way to explain that. It's not a useful feature, because in practice, you always want to search backwards.

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts with *"Alt"* may conflict with shortcuts in the GUI (say, using the terminal window on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)).

Answer (score 0):

`character-search` (`C-]`) and `character-search-backward` (`M-C-]`) may be what you want, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html

Besides that, if using the `C-r` / `C-s` searches, I hit the `ESC` key to get back into "edit mode" with the cursor position now at the start of the found search term.