# How to reverse-i-search back and forth?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, search

I use `reverse-i-search` often, and that's cool. Sometime though when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> multiple times, I *pass* the command I am actually looking for. Because <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> searches backward in history, from newest to oldest, I have to:

1. cancel,
2. search again and
3. stop exactly at the command, without passing it.

While in `reverse-i-search` prompt, is it possible to search forward, i.e. from where I stand to newest. I naively tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, no luck. I heard about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> but this is not what I am expecting here. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: It is more a superuser question I supposed: http://superuser.com/questions/472846/how-to-reverse-i-search-back-and-forth

Comment: On Ubuntu it's definitely `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Comment: @m-ric you say it is more a superuser question. Here it has 88 up-votes. At superuser it has 6 up-votes.

Comment: @valk no, on Ubuntu 20.04 inside WSL2 `Ctrl+Shift+R` does exactly the same thing as `Ctrl+R`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There is a similar question here:

[Control-r reverse-i-search in Bash: how do you "reset" the search in Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549810/control-r-reverse-i-search-in-cygwin-bash-how-do-you-reset-the-search)

Found another similar question on Super User:

[(reverse-i-search) in Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/159106/reverse-i-search-in-bash)

Apparently, both mention <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, which may do the trick.

Comment: ctrl-s - standard emacs.

Comment: Important: To make `^-S` work, add `stty -ixon` to your bash profile (`~/.bashrc` on Linux, `~/.bash_profile` on OSX). Also note that reversing direction by pressing the respective other keyboard shortcut is initially a _no-op_ - all that changes is the display's prefix (`reverse-i-search` vs. `i-search`). Thus, to actually *take 1 step* in the other direction, press the keyboard shortcut *twice*.

Comment: What does no-op mean? What does `stty -ixon` do exactly?

Comment: @zyxue noop means "no operation." It means that the shortcut is mapped to "do nothing." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP). Without setting `-ixon`, ctrl-s tells the terminal to stop updating meaning you to have to push ctrl-q to resume normal operation. By setting `-ixon` you disable that behavior, which maps ctrl-s to `i-search`.

Comment: @gdupont it looks like i-search is part of readline. The source is here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/isearch.c?h=devel

Answer (score 62):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

...solved it for me AFTER using...

```
stty -ixon
```

If CTRL+S doesn't work for you is because according to [Vincenzo Pii's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760474/reverse-intelligent-search-reverse-i-search-how-to-get-previous-result?rq=1) accepted answer in another related thread:

> The problem is that this binding, in many terminals, is used by default to send the pause transmission code (`XOF`).
>
> As in `man stty`:
>
> > ```
> > [-]ixon
> >     enable XON/XOFF flow control
> > ```
>
> So, if you have this option enabled on your terminal (the output of `stty -a` contains `ixon` withouth the `-` sign in front), you cannot use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the context of *reverse-i-search*.
>
> To disable it, use the following command:
>
> ```
> stty -ixon
> ```
>
> And <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will give you a `(i-search)` (non reverse).

Comment: In my case `-ixon` is disabled but for some reason ^S symbols is still installed literally. I'm on `lxterminal`.

Answer (score 7):

Try `delete`, magically worked.

Others point to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try running `stty -ixon` first. If that helps, add it to your bash profile.

Comment: It works, but could you please explain what does `stty -ixon` do exactly?

Comment: delete didn't do anything for me

Comment: I couldn't get `stty -ixon` to work, but hitting the `delete` key while doing a `bck-i-search` worked. It goes to the previous search result. Thank you @advisor21!