# Reverse intelligent search (reverse-i-search), how to get previous result?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

When doing reverse intelligent search on a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), I can keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to go back in "history" and get older commands containing my search string.

How can I move back to a result which I have already displayed (a previous search result)?

Comment: Your question belongs on SU, where it [has been answered](http://superuser.com/a/159184) already.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Funny that the accepted answer to that question on SU links a question on SO... Reverse-i-search IS a tool for developers.

Comment: So eventually this has answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549810/control-r-reverse-i-search-in-cygwin-bash-how-do-you-reset-the-search/549860#549860

Comment: @VincenzoPii no. reverse search is a feature of a shell. The shell is a tool _used by_ developers. And, yes, it _is_ funny that [SU] links to [SO] for that answer :/ (+1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I want to leave a reference for people who may find this, as the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549810/control-r-reverse-i-search-in-cygwin-bash-how-do-you-reset-the-search) actually asks for something else (even if one of the answers contains the solution to this problem).

The key binding to move forward is <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

The problem is that this binding, in many terminals, is used by default to send the pause transmission code (`XOF`).

As in `man stty`:

```
   [-]ixon
          enable XON/XOFF flow control
```

So, if you have this option enabled on your terminal (the output of `stty -a` contains `ixon` withouth the `-` sign in front), you cannot use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in the context of reverse-i-search.

To disable it, use the following command:

```
stty -ixon
```

And <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will give you a `(i-search)` (non reverse).

Comment: Woah. I never knew that +1

Comment: How do I make the terminal change permanent?

Comment: @vishalm, just use your ~/.bashrc (or whatever your system uses), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900803/persistent-stty-settings

Comment: @VincenzoPii Thanks, that's what I am using now (.bashrc)

Comment: but what if I don't want to discard the pause function of 'ctrl+s'.   Can I solve the conflict?