# Persistent stty Settings?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Currently, I can disable the terminal output suspend/resume "feature" (CTRL+S and CTRL+Q nonsense) by executing `stty -ixon`.

Unfortunately this is not permanent. I need to set this option *everytime* I launch `xterm`.

Is there a file that can be edited that would remember my setting and keep it permanent across re-launches and reboots?

Comment: Usually `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`, depending on your preferred shell.

Comment: I had tried that before coming here. It seems that I must manage the creation the /dev/tty* files, or do something about the mappings in /etc/ttytype. I'm not sure which process or how the /dev/tty files are created, and what actually sets the tty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits go to PHS. Symlinking .bashrc to .profile actually worked. Wow, I thought bash would read .profile by default.

Thanks Phs.